# Cast Button is not Showing in Actionbar in my application

Tags: android

**CastOptionsProvider class**

```
public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

 @Override
 public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {

        return new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) 
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
}

 private MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem;

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);

        mediaRouteMenuItem =
                CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(),
                        menu,
                        R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        return true;
    }
```

Dependecies

```
dependencies{
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:9.4.0'
}
```

Comment: I AM ALSO ADDING
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
<item
        android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
       
 android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
 app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>


 

 <meta-data
            android:name=     "com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
            android:value="com.livevideoapp.Utils.CastOptionsProvider" />

Comment: PLEASE HELP AND SUGGEST ME.....